# Determinant for equivalent matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

$A$ be a non singular matrix of order $4$ and $B$ is the matrix obtained from $A$ by adding twice of it's first row to third row, then find the determinant of $2A^{-1}B$ ?

I'm confused about determinant of equivalent matrices. Is this the right approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a multiple of a line to another line doesn't change the determinant and $\det(A^{-1})=\det^{-1}(A)$, hence $$\det(2A^{-1}B)=2^4\det(A^{-1})\det(B)=2^4\frac{\det A}{\det A}=16.$$

Comment: can we say equivalent matrices have the same determinant?

Comment: @SULTAN I think you're confusing **Similarity**. For similarity $B=PAP^{-1}$ and $\det B=\det(A)\det(P)\det^{-1}(P)=\det A$. For equivalent matrices $B=PAQ$ (for $P\in GL_n(F),Q\in GL_m(F),A\in GL_{n\times m}(F)$). You'll need to assume $n=m$ (since otherwise $\det A$ is vague). In that case since equality of square matrices implies equality of determinants it means they do have the same determinant.

Comment: ohh got it......

Answer (score 1):

Determinants of equivalent matrices are not same in general but here you are adding rows ,therefore determinant remains same.

Yes, if two matrices are similar then their trace/rank/determinant/eigenvalue will be equal.